# Combo Box Display Member not changed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, combobox

I have used a ComboBox in my Form and use Entity Framework for its datasource, my code is:

```
            publishContext = new publishingCompanyEntities();
            comboBox2.DataSource = publishContext.Authors;
            comboBox2.DisplayMember = "FirstName";
            MessageBox.Show(comboBox2.DisplayMember.ToString());//this line return null !
```

Although I changed the `DisplayMember` of the ComboBox, the MessageBox returns null value,
ComboBox is not filled with data, and database has data and `publishContext.Authors` returns them, but ComboBox does not show them!

Comment: display member should Declare before data source !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show your message box like i mentioned.

```
publishContext = new publishingCompanyEntities();
comboBox2.DisplayMember = "FirstName";
comboBox2.DataSource = publishContext.Authors.ToList();
MessageBox.Show(publishContext.Authors.Count().ToString());
```

Now check that is it null now if null then use try catch block for exact error

```
try
{
publishContext = new publishingCompanyEntities();
comboBox2.DisplayMember = "FirstName";
comboBox2.DataSource = publishContext.Authors.ToList();
MessageBox.Show(publishContext.Authors.Count().ToString());
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

Or you may check this [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/c71f0f95-3f88-4b04-9e95-11dd15b11d37) as well

Hope it works...

Comment: problem was from sort of lines ! display member should Declare before data source ! now display member has been changed , but yet combobox has now item and `cmoAuthors.Items.Count` return 0  as `publishContext.Authors` has Item! why ?

Comment: where you change your display member.

Comment: before setting combo box data source

Comment: what do you mean `tablename`

Comment: that was wrong way, i edit my answer again and also paste a link as well. now check my answer again..thanks

Comment: yes , thats right . i used `.ToList()` to cast DbSet to list to use it for dataSource , thx